# Javascript forEach to modify numeric arrays with a function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am trying to perform a calculation for each set of number within both arrays

```
    var close_px = [];
    close_px.push([9,9.5,10.2,10.3,10.6]);
    close_px.push([5,5.7,5.3,5.1,5,6]);
    close_px.forEach(element => element / element[0]-1);
```

What I am trying to output is each array calculated as a percentage move away from the initial number.

For the first array it would be:

```
    1: 9 /9 -1
    2: 9.5/9 - 1
    3: 10.2/9 - 1
    4: 10.3/9 - 1
    5: 10.6/9 - 1
```

Comment: Typically you would include an explanation of what's going wrong or at least ask a question.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` is for *side effects*, but I do not see any changes. `Array.prototype.map` is for transformation via the function's return value for each element.

Comment: What are you expecting here?

Comment: close_px.forEach(element => element / element[0]-1); is not getting processed.  I believe the function is being applied to the array itself not to the data.

Comment: This line doesn't have any kind of result:  `close_px.forEach(element => element / element[0]-1);` - it does nothing.

Comment: Should I use it to push the results to a new array?  or can I change the values inplace?

Comment: pctChange = close_px.map(p => p / close_px[0] - 1);  This works for one array but I want to do it for more than one at once.

Comment: You should do it like this `close_px = [...[9,9.5,10.2,10.3,10.6],...[5,5.7,5.3,5.1,5,6]]`

because at the beginning you pushed an array to `close_px ` you need push their values

`close_px.forEach(element => console.log(element / close_px[0] - 1));`

Comment: I get 2 NaN's for that

Comment: for example:

x = [9,9.5,10.2,10.3,10.6];
const pct = x.map(p => p / x[0] - 1); 

returns
[0, 0.05555555555555558, 0.1333333333333333, 0.1444444444444446, 0.1777777777777778]

I want to perform the same logic within a forEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got the point, but this might be what you need:

```js
const close_px = [];
close_px.push([9,9.5,10.2,10.3,10.6]);
close_px.push([5,5.7,5.3,5.1,5,6]);
const result = close_px.map(array => array.map(element => element / array[0] - 1));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Exactly, for each on the array and then map the element :)